# spread an island of non-zero elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with some non-zero (let's say `=11`) elements

```
a=zeros(6,3);
a(3,1)=11;
a(4,1)=11;
a(6,1)=11;
a(1,2)=11;
a

a =

     0    11     0
     0     0     0
    11     0     0
    11     0     0
     0     0     0
    11     0     0
```

I want these elements to "spread" to neighbouring zero elements, meaning that all the zero elements contiguous to a non-zero should become non-zero. The expected output for the case above should be:

```
11    11    11
11    11     0
11    11     0
11    11     0
11     0     0
11    11     0
```

My idea was to set to non-zero all the points where the gradient of the original matrix is non-zero:

```
[dx,dy] = gradient(a);
a(find(dx~=0))=11
a(find(dy~=0))=11
```

> a =
>
> ```
> 11    11    11
>  0     0     0
> 11    11     0
> 11    11     0
>  0     0     0
> 11    11     0
> ```
>
> a =
>
> ```
> 11    11    11
> 11    11     0
> 11    11     0
> 11    11     0
>  0     0     0
> 11    11     0
> ```

But it is not working because the gradient is zero for elements surrounded by non-zero elements. For the element (5,1) in my example: -5.5 + 5.5 = 0

Can someone suggest some alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you had pointed out, the idea of the gradient is in trouble when it meets `[11 0 11]` or `[11 0 11]'`, but we could resolve it by changing the number in it. i.e. the gradient of `[11 0 12]` is `[-11 0.5 12]`.

```
clc; clear;
%data
a=zeros(6,3);
a(3,1)=11;
a(4,1)=11;
a(6,1)=11;
a(1,2)=11;
a

%change the number in the matrix
ind=find(a ~= 0);
a(ind)=rand(length(ind),1)*10;

%spread out non-zero elements
[dx,dy] = gradient(a);
a(find(dx~=0))=11;
a(find(dy~=0))=11;
a
```

Output:

```
a =

     0    11     0
     0     0     0
    11     0     0
    11     0     0
     0     0     0
    11     0     0


a =

    11    11    11
    11    11     0
    11    11     0
    11    11     0
    11     0     0
    11    11     0
```

Comment: That is a smart one!

Comment: This looks a bit like one step of a morphological PDE (the dilation as suggested by jodag can be approximated with a morphological PDE).

Comment: Yeap. In my point of view, many image processing steps are actually PDE. i.e. the extraction of the boundary. (Although I know quite a little about them.)

Answer (score 5):

FYI what you've described is more formally known as a [dilation operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)).

A few alternatives to what you've tried.

**1**. If you have the image processing toolbox you can use `imdilate` with a cross-shaped window.

```
% define a cross-shaped window
se = strel('diamond',1);
a = imdilate(a, se);
```

**2**. If you have the image processing toolbox you can use `ordfilt2`. This is performing max filtering using a cross-shaped window.

```
% build cross shaped window
win = [0 1 0
       1 1 1
       0 1 0];
% max filter
ord = sum(win(:));
a = ordfilt2(a, ord, win);
```

**3**. If you don't have image processing toolbox you could get the result by shifting logical indexes around.

```
[r,c] = size(a);
idx1 = a>0;
idx2 = [idx1(2:end,:); false(1,c)];
idx3 = [false(1,c); idx1(1:(end-1),:)];
idx4 = [idx1(:,2:end) false(r,1)];
idx5 = [false(r,1) idx1(:,1:(end-1))];
idx_all = idx1 | idx2 | idx3 | idx4 | idx5;

a(idx_all) = 11;
```

Comment: Cool! Learned a lot in it.

Comment: XD The name "dilatation" makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) to find indices of neighbors:

```
mask = [ 0 1 0 
         1 0 1
         0 1 0 ];

a(conv2(a,mask,'same')~=0)=11;
```